# Load autogenerated classes in Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, winforms

My app dynamically create class based on database table structure auto generate model class and save it in `debug` directory. I want to move that class file in development solution directory and include it in project.

My code for generating:

```
   public string GenerateModelClass(string tableName)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "GenCSharpModel;";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("pTableName", tableName));


                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        result = reader[0].ToString();

                        if(!Directory.Exists("Generated"))
                        {
                            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory("Generated");
                        }

                        File.WriteAllText("Generated/" + tableName+".cs", result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is dynamicly created c# class in `debug/Generated` directory :

```
**output > result = reader[0].ToString();**


public class Person 
{
    public strin Name;
    public ing Age;
}
```

This class need to include in project. How to include it ?

[image]

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: New created class to include in project.

Comment: you need to add a reference to the file in your .prj file

Comment: In which project? The current project? You'd likely need to modify the project file then somehow trigger visual studio to load the updated project.

Comment: Nice you understand what i need.  It is posible to update `.prj` programaticly ?

Comment: This seems a bit backward. You want your project to compile and run, and then generate a file that gets added to the project so that it can be compiled again?

Comment: Generally, the way you work with something like this is you create a tool that creates the extra source files.  You package the tool as something like a Visual Studio Extension.  Then, you use the tool to create source files for the projects you are working on.  An example of an extension like this is the _Reverse POCO Generator_ (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator & https://reversepoco.co.uk/)

Comment: On .NET Core you should use Source Generator instead, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/